# Mustache.js using current each as index

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, mustache

I am currently iterating over a group of items in my template like so (names changed for simplicity):

```
{{#myArray}}
  <tr>
    <td>{{name}}</td>
    <td>{{type_id}}</td>
    <td>{{anotherArray[type_id].name}}</td>
  </tr>
{{/myArray}}
```

Where `anotherArray` has type_id as its key and a name attribute on the value.

I have tested and type_id does print its value, and when I lookup my array in the chrome javascript console it can find the array index (and the name property) just fine.

How should I correctly lookup an array with a variable of the current `each` loop in Mustache.js?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mustache is intentionally simple so there's very little that you can do inside the template. If you need anything beyond simple iteration (`{{#ary}}`) and interpolation (`{{val}}`) then you'll have to preprocess the data in JavaScript before the template sees it:

```
var data = [ ];
for(var i = 0; i < myArray.length; ++i)
    data.push({
        name: myArray[i].name,
        type_id: myArray[i].type_id,
        other_name: anotherArray[myArray[i].type_id]].name
    });
```

Then you'd feed `data` to a template like this:

```
{{#data}}
  <tr>
    <td>{{name}}</td>
    <td>{{type_id}}</td>
    <td>{{other_name}}</td>
  </tr>
{{/data}}
```

Comment: Yeh I had a feeling that would be the case (having to pass more data in a different form to the template). Thanks anyway.